# When will I stop receiving TransactionStatus updates for a transaction submitted via author_submitAndWatchExtrinsic?

Tags: extrinsic, rpc, transaction-pool

If I submit a transaction via "author_submitAndWatchExtrinsic", I start getting back TransactionStatus updates, which look like one of these:

```rust
pub enum TransactionStatus<Hash, BlockHash> {
    /// Transaction is part of the future queue.
    Future,
    /// Transaction is part of the ready queue.
    Ready,
    /// The transaction has been broadcast to the given peers.
    Broadcast(Vec<String>),
    /// Transaction has been included in block with given hash
    /// at the given position.
    #[serde(with = "v1_compatible")]
    InBlock((BlockHash, TxIndex)),
    /// The block this transaction was included in has been retracted.
    Retracted(BlockHash),
    /// Maximum number of finality watchers has been reached,
    /// old watchers are being removed.
    FinalityTimeout(BlockHash),
    /// Transaction has been finalized by a finality-gadget, e.g GRANDPA.
    #[serde(with = "v1_compatible")]
    Finalized((BlockHash, TxIndex)),
    /// Transaction has been replaced in the pool, by another transaction
    /// that provides the same tags. (e.g. same (sender, nonce)).
    Usurped(Hash),
    /// Transaction has been dropped from the pool because of the limit.
    Dropped,
    /// Transaction is no longer valid in the current state.
    Invalid,
}
```

(see https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/4bf67fb3dc0f095e4210b5ebc5f1f2ea24bf36c0/client/transaction-pool/api/src/lib.rs#L107)

The docs above this enum state:

```
/// The stream is considered finished only when either `Finalized` or `FinalityTimeout`
/// event is triggered. You are however free to unsubscribe from notifications at any point.
```

So my questions are:

1. Will I *always* eventually receive either a `Finalized` or `FinalityTimeout` notification for some transaction I submit (even if it becomes `Invalid`, say)?
2. If the answer is "no" to the above: Would I be right to assume that the last `TransactionStatus` received before the stream is dropped is indicative of what happened to the transaction (ie perhaps it became `Invalid` or whatever).
3. If I set a fixed mortality on some transaction, will it lead to the subscription being ended sooner (either with `Finalized` or `FinalityTimeout` or perhaps just with `Invalid`)?

Ultimately, I am asking these with this Subxt logic in mind, and want to see if there is any way to improve it: https://github.com/paritytech/subxt/blob/42bcddeecb39db98e711075b44331d24a8fbeb4d/subxt/src/tx/tx_progress.rs#L102

Answer (score 1):

I have made an investigation, and find something interesting. The Stream trait implemented for TxProgress will end only when the event FinalityTimeout or Finalized received.  But I found the RPC server of substrate will remove subscribers when the usurped,  invalid, dropped, finalized or finality_timeout received. So I'm curious whether TxProgress would drop the connection and stop waiting for new events?

Please find below some relevant code snippets:

[TxProgress](https://github.com/paritytech/subxt/blob/a2b8dde5e6d0a6e9c81a6b3d4bebe5177dc7899a/subxt/src/tx/tx_progress.rs#L137-L181)

Below is Listener, the server side corresponding to the client of subscribition. It will fire a event when the transaction status changed, and it will close the connection if `h.is_done()` returns true. You could find the code [here](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/75dee3c6fc72f6399a43f498e0e42f94fb82a7bd/client/transaction-pool/src/graph/listener.rs#L44-L59)

```
impl<H: hash::Hash + traits::Member + Serialize, C: ChainApi> Listener<H, C> {
    fn fire<F>(&mut self, hash: &H, fun: F)
    where
        F: FnOnce(&mut watcher::Sender<H, ExtrinsicHash<C>>),
    {
        let clean = if let Some(h) = self.watchers.get_mut(hash) {
            fun(h);
            h.is_done()
        } else {
            false
        };


        if clean {
            self.watchers.remove(hash);
        }
    }
```

And `h` is a instance of [Sender](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/75dee3c6fc72f6399a43f498e0e42f94fb82a7bd/client/transaction-pool/src/graph/watcher.rs#L51-L54). It's method `is_done` returns true if `is_finalized` is true, or it's subscribers is empty.

```
pub fn is_done(&self) -> bool {
        self.is_finalized || self.receivers.is_empty()
}
```

And you could find relevent codes [here](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/75dee3c6fc72f6399a43f498e0e42f94fb82a7bd/client/transaction-pool/src/graph/watcher.rs#L81), the Sender will change `is_finalized` to true, if the event is usurped, finalized, finality_timeout, invalid or dropped.